# Performing bitwise operations on IPAddress

Tags: vb.net, ip-address, bitwise-operators

I was really surprised when I found out I can't simply do this:

```
    Dim ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3")
    Dim mask = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0")

    ' next lines won't compile
    Dim networkAddress = ip And mask ' would produce 192.168.1.0
    Dim broadcastAddress = ip Or (Not mask) ' would produce 192.168.1.255
```

So before I go and implement this type of functionality myself on a subclass: am I missing something obvious? Is there a reason why this wasn't implemented that I'm overlooking?

I admit I might not have paid as much attention during my networking classes as I probably should have.

**EDIT**

I came up with this block of code:

```
    Dim ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3")
    Dim mask = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0")

    Dim ipUnsignedInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ip.GetAddressBytes, 0)
    Dim maskUnsignedInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt32(mask.GetAddressBytes, 0)

    Dim networkAddressUnsignedInteger = ipUnsignedInteger And maskUnsignedInteger
    Dim networkAddress = New IPAddress(networkAddressUnsignedInteger)

    Dim broadcastAddressUnsignedInteger = ipUnsignedInteger Or (Not maskUnsignedInteger)
    Dim broadcastAddress = New IPAddress(broadcastAddressUnsignedInteger)
```

It works, but it's an incredible amount of extra code for something that seems so obvious to me! Why is this not part of the framework?!

Comment: Try use the CLng function to convert ip to a long integer and also the mask to a long integer. That will probably help.

Comment: Thanks! I used unsigned integers since ipv4 uses only 4 bytes. Now I just need an answer to the "why" part.

Comment: You're trying to use an IP address as a subnet mask? I don't think that's a common thing to do (apples and oranges), and that might be the reason for it not being part of the framework.

Comment: What do you mean? I know they're not valid IP addresses, but nothing prevents you from creating an instance of `IPAddress` that is a subnet mask. As far as I can tell they're identical objects but with different purposes.

Comment: The WHY? Your original code return an object. Variable ip is an Object not an integer. So if you parse IPv6 it will make more than 4 bytes. That is why. So now you get the result as four bytes because it was IPv4 address. To make this as fast as possible you must parse the string manually convert each sub-integer into a byte, and then combine the bytes into a four byte integer using ANDS and SHIFTS. Otherwise you are stuck with the IPAddress way and it creates entire array objects just to read the four bytes.

Comment: Not true, you don't have to explicitly specify the variable type if you initialize it on the same line. Not even if you set option explicit on.

Comment: Anyway you're missing the point: the question is why `IPAddress` doesn't implement `And` / `Or` / `<<` / `>>` operators.

Comment: @lejon If you look at [UnicastIPAddressInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation.aspx), it has a property `IPv4Mask` of type `IPAddress`. Just to prove I'm not doing anything strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim networkaddress2 As New IPAddress(ip.Address And mask.Address)
Dim broadcastAddress2 = New IPAddress(CUInt(ip.Address) Or (Not CUInt(mask.Address)))
```

Be warned that IPAddress.Address is deprecated however.

Comment: Nice find! I've already created my own implementation that uses `GetAddressBytes`, but this is pretty much what I was looking for.